# Text searching in Array

Tags: php, arrays

```
<<
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => soccer player
                    [1] => soccer player athlete who play soccer
                    [2] => sport
                    [3] => soccer
                    [4] => soccer football game in which two team of 11 player try to kick or head ball into opponent goal
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => soccer player
                    [1] => soccer player athlete who play soccer
                    [2] => play
                    [3] => activity
                    [4] => actor
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => soccer player
                    [1] => soccer player athlete who play soccer
                    [2] => player
                    [3] => commercial enterprise activity of provide good and service involve financial and commercial and industrial aspect
                    [4] => player person who participate in or be skilled at some game
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => soccer player
                    [1] => soccer player athlete who play soccer
                    [2] => athlete person train to compete in sport
                    [3] => athlete person train to compete in sport
                    [4] => athlete person train to compete in sport
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => athlete
                    [1] => athlete person train to compete in sport
                    [2] => sport
                    [3] => sport
                    [4] => sport
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => athlete
                    [1] => athlete person train to compete in sport
                    [2] => compete compete for something
                    [3] => compete compete for something
                    [4] => compete compete for something
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => athlete
                    [1] => athlete person train to compete in sport
                    [2] => train
                    [3] => train create by train and teach
                    [4] => train public transport provide by line of railway car couple together and draw by locomotive
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => athlete
                    [1] => athlete person train to compete in sport
                    [2] => person
                    [3] => person
                    [4] => person
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [0] => athlete
                    [1] => athlete person train to compete in sport
                    [2] => athlete person train to compete in sport
                    [3] => athlete person train to compete in sport
                    [4] => athlete person train to compete in sport
                )

        )

>>
```

Hi

I need a php searching code for an Array shown above. But the search shouldn't be an exact string match like for instance i am searching for `"11 player"` it should give me result `Array[0]` as it is mentioned in `Array[0][0][4]`...

Comment: I am not getting an idea how to do it

Comment: what about reading the documentation for [array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php)?

Answer (score 0):

You need a simple recursive search function like that.

```
<?php
    function recursive_search($array,$text,$path = "")
    {
        $result = array();
        foreach($array as $index => $value)
        {
            if(is_array($value))
                $result = array_merge($result,recursive_search($value,$text,$path . '/' . $index));
            else if(strpos($value,$text) !== false)
                $result[] = array('path' => $path . '/' . $index,'value' => $value); 
                //$result[] = $value; // use this line and delete above if you dont want path.


        }

        return $result;

    }
```

Usage

```
 $my_array =
    array(
        array(
            array(
                "soccer player",
                "soccer player athlete who play soccer",
                "player",
                "commercial enterprise activity of provide good and service involve financial and commercial and industrial aspect",
                "player person who participate in or be skilled at some game",
                "soccer football game in which two team of 11 player try to kick or head ball into opponent goal"
            )
        ) ,
        array(
            "soccer player",
            "soccer player athlete who play soccer",
            "player",
            "commercial enterprise activity of provide good and service involve financial and commercial and industrial aspect",
            "player person who participate in or be skilled at some game",
            "soccer football game in which two team of 11 player try to kick or head ball into opponent goal"
        )
    );



    $elements = recursive_search($my_array,"11 player");

    var_dump($elements);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [path] => /0/0/5
            [value] => soccer football game in which two team of 11 player try to kick or head ball into opponent goal
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [path] => /1/5
            [value] => soccer football game in which two team of 11 player try to kick or head ball into opponent goal
        )

)
```

if you want elements without path output will be something like that

```
Array
(
    [0] => soccer football game in which two team of 11 player try to kick or head ball into opponent goal
    [1] => soccer football game in which two team of 11 player try to kick or head ball into opponent goal
)
```